# C++ newline fails diff test?

Tags: c++, formatting, output, diff, newline

So I have a two programs that I am comparing output to.  Whenever it does a newline, it says my output is different using a diff utility.
I have tried using:

```
std::cout << endl;
```

and

```
std::cout << '\n';
```

but it winmerge still says that our output is different.  I am running both executables on the same machine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There *is* textmode translation on windows, normally.

Comment: I have tried that but the results were strange.  Not only did it change MY output, but the output from the other program had weird formatting issues with newline.  Any idea why?

Comment: @scorxcho: Too vague, no details.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file in binary mode and check the byte values for the newline.

One will probably be a char with ASCII code 10

and the other will be 10 and 13.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming `std::endl` is equivalent to streaming `'\n'` then `std::flush` so, no, you won't see any differences. More likely your tool is expecting to find a Windows-style line ending (that is, CRLF rather than just LF).

```
std::cout << "\r\n" << std::flush;
```

But, instead of guessing, you should simply open up that comparison data in a hex editor and see for yourself what characters are expected.

Comment: Can you explain how to "open comparison data in a hex editor" so I can "see what's expected?"

Comment: @scorxcho: not sure "teaching how to read files" is within the scope of this question. Suffice it to say, whatever editor you use for programming should be capable of showing you precisely what is in any given text or binary file. Notepad++?